# Synonyms for "previous"?

Tags: synonyms

I looked up the synonym for *previous* up in the dictionary, and found

> preceding, former, earlier, etc.

Are there other synonyms for this word which can be used in writing a scientific paper? For example: In the *previous* studies...

Comment: **earlier** comes to mind...

Comment: Many: https://www.google.com/search?q=preceding+synonyms - aforegoing, antecedent

Comment: Journal articles, especially scientific literature, isn't the best place to try out new descriptive writing. There's kind of a *tried and true* method of communicating things. That's part of their readability.

Comment: ...Yes. I hope mplungian's 'aforegoing' is meant as a joke.

Comment: Since you can't write about papers that are **not** previous, or former, the word adds nothing.  Just name the studies. Or say studies.

Comment: @Oldcat That is very often the case, but there may also be occasions where a researcher is aware of relevant research being conducted by someone else that is still in progress, or where the associated paper is still awaiting publication.

Comment: @ErikKowal - If so, then that would be "forthcoming" or "unpublished" rather than prior.

Comment: @Oldcat Yes, quite so.

Comment: @Oldcat I got your point. But doesn't it sound a bit weird if I say "Studies found that.." when I quote some findings from previous studies?

Comment: If you are being precise, you should be naming them. Then you can use the author name:  Oldcat, et al. (1997) found that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Former* and *ex-* don't work in relation to scientific papers. *Previous* and *earlier* are both good; *preceding* would also work in the narrower context of a study leading up to the one currently being focused on.

For example:

> In 2000, John Masterson showed that rats fed a diet of marijuana consistently preferred to drink single-malt Scotch whisky, whereas his **preceding** 1998 study demonstrated that coca-fed rats had a preference for blended American rye.

Lists of synonyms taken from a thesaurus must be approached cautiously, because few words that are described as synonyms can be used interchangeably. If you have no educated native speaker to guide you, the next-best approach is to Google the individual words in the list to get a feel for how they are being used in the context of the online text segments in which they occur.

Comment: I must have missed the 1998 study.

Comment: As well as *prior*

Comment: @bib Agreed. I overlooked that one.

Answer (score 0):

you can have these terms as synonyms for "previous"

earlier, past, prior, former, erstwhile, antecedent, ex, precedent

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is actually meant here by "[previous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/previous)," you also might want to consider "aforementioned," and "[afore](http://www.yourdictionary.com/afore)."

**Afore**: before: *aforementioned*.

> [Would you accept the afore figures as accurate without any additional information being given? Answer Yes or No and explain the basis for your view.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=7aGPAAAAQBAJ&pg=PR100&lpg=PR100&dq=%22the+afore+figures%22&source=bl&ots=MHMjC%5fuKAe&sig=X0SN9O-rgoZRblKUL4tE2WJihYA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=R99LU%5fuCIOHa0QWw1oHoDg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20afore%20figures%22&f=false)